# How to change default skin in dnn 7 via database?

Tags: default, skin, dotnetnuke-7

How to change default skin in **dnn7** by database?

Answer (score 1):

This is the the query to be used :

```
UPDATE         HostSettings
SET            SettingValue = 'your skin address'
WHERE          SettingName = 'DefaultPortalSkin'
OR             SettingName = 'DefaultAdminSkin'
```

your skin address format: `[G]Skins/SkinMain/skin.ascx`